# jQuery Mobile and textarea rows

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, textarea, rows

So, I'ld like to display a `textarea` on just 1 row.

But jQuery Mobile doesn't think so... Whatever value I set in the `rows` attribute, it always is 2 rows height...

Would it have any solution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The jQuery Mobile CSS sets a specific height for `textarea` elements:

```
textarea.ui-input-text {
    height : 50px;

    -webkit-transition : height 200ms linear;
       -moz-transition : height 200ms linear;
         -o-transition : height 200ms linear;
            transition : height 200ms linear;
}
```

You can create your own rule to override this height to something more single-line:

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-input-text {
    height : 25px;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mEs8U/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use max-height to set the autogrowing limits to textarea.

```
textarea.ui-input-text {
    max-height : 100px;
}
```